# XML File Parse in javascript how to. Large File maybe use SAX?

Tags: javascript, xml, file, sax

G'day All,

I am pulling my hair out, getting headaches and my eyes hurt. I have been hither and thither and I seem to get whither.

This will be my first experience with xml and would really want to get this working. It is a large file. Well large in my eyes +-5mb. I can not imagine that this file would be loaded into memory to process. Users will get a bit peeved with this.

Basically we are using a 3rd parties site to do our ecommerce. So we have no access to the database other than via the admin area.

What we want to do is make sure that there is no stuff ups when it comes to addresses. Therefore we got this xml file put together listing all postcodes with areas and states:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<POSTCODES>
    <PostCode id="2035">
        <Area>2035 1</Area>
        <Area>2035 2</Area>
        <Area>2035 3</Area>
        <State>NSW</State>
    </Postcode>
    <PostCode id="2038">
        <Area>2038 1</Area>
        <Area>2038 2</Area>
        <Area>2038 3</Area>
        <State>NSW</State>
    </Postcode>
    <PostCode id="2111">
        <Area>2111 1</Area>
        <Area>2111 2</Area>
        <Area>2111 3</Area>
        <State>NSW</State>
    </Postcode>
</POSTCODES>
```

Someone suggested SAX but suddenly died when asked how? The web is not helping unless I am not looking properly. I see a lot of examples. Either they do not show how to read the file but rather do it from a textarea or the example is in java.

What do we want? User enters a post code of 2038. We want to go to the javascript with that data and have returned to us all the suburbs that full within that post code.

Anyone out there that can please tell me what to download and how to use it to get what i need?

Please, please, please. It is hard to see a grown man begging and crying but I am.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a script on the server which will suggest suburbs based on the users postcode selection? You could use jQuery's ajax functionality to do this.

You might also be able to use jQueryUI's autocomplete control to parse XML and make suggestions: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#xml

It's also possible to do this entirely in javascript without any script on the server side, but it would be pretty slow at loading if the XML file is 5MB. You might be able to get a significant reduction in file size thought by gzipping it before transmission from the server.

Comment: +1 - Doing this in JavaScript would simply be improper.  Just because you 'can' do something one way doesn't mean you should.

At worst, you could set up an external server and use JSONp to move data across domains.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse this in Javascript, you can use jQuery.
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery